# How to avoid `ActiveRecordObject(#69859840542640) expected, got String(#19082040)`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I understand that, I had `belongs_to :ActiveRecordObject` ain the Active Record model and following in the partial `_form.html`:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :ActiveRecordObject %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :ActiveRecordObject %>
  </div>
```

So I hit this error:

`ActiveRecordObject(#69859840542640) expected, got String(#19082040)`

I don't want to change `ActiveRecordObject` to something else yet to accept string, how can I do that?

NOTE: tried with `attr_accessor` with the same name.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this code?

Comment: I want to get a string as `param[:key]` and create a database entry with it.

Comment: Either you can create a model attribute for this or use a nested form.

Answer (score 1):

I use:
Book -> Author.

```
View Edit Author:
  <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :author_id %><br>
  <%= collection_select(:book, :author_id, Author.all, :id, :full_name, {}, {:class=>'form-control', :style => 'width: 25%'}) %>
  </div>
```

View Show Book:

```
<p>
  <strong>Autor:</strong>
  <%= @book.author.full_name %>
</p>

In Model Author:

  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
```

**I hope you to help**

Answer (score -2):

You should consider using 'simple_form'.
https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

For belongs_to :category association

```
= f.association :category
```

Refer question: [rails 4 simple_form belongs_to association undefined method error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21318644)